# How do I keep my splash screen over React components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put a splash screen on my app. However, React is rendering its components above the splash screen.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id='overlay'>
   <img/>
</div>
<div id='root'></div>

#overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(36,79,53, 1); 
  z-index: 99; 
}

#root{
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Look into React portals https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: That bit you posted looks fine to me, do you have any styles on `#root`?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't look like I can help much with what's given, every thing seems to line up correctly. There's something outside of what you've posted that's messing it up. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdPgpV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this up for a bit, run the snippet, you can see the problem is not with the code you posted. I made the overlay a bit transparent so you can see it is over the red text below.

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {title} = this.props;
    console.log("rendered");
    return (
      <div className="thingy">
        <div>{title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(36,79,53, .7); 
  z-index: 99; 
}

#root{
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
.thingy{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='overlay'>
   <img/>
</div>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your response led me to look at the z-indexes of the  components. They were not set at all, so I set them to 1 and it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to create a react component that would render as part of the react application. That way you can programmatically control when the overlap appears relative to the rest of your application logic.  Since you already have the CSS, and markup, you just need to put it into a component and render it.

Comment: React provides a clean solution for exactly this use case: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Thanks Rob. I forgot to mention I tried putting it in my App as well. I tried putting it in every position with the other components that were being loaded, still the same issue.

Comment: @SakoBu Thanks. But I'm not sure that does what I am needing. It turns out I just needed to set a z-index for the components.